# Can't execute python using IronPython in Unity

Tags: python, c#, unity-game-engine, matplotlib, ironpython

I try to execute a function on python from a unity C# script and I'm using the package "IronPython", but on my python file I'm using - matplotlib.pyplot and I get from my unity editor the next error:

```
ImportException: No module named matplotlib.pyplot
Microsoft.Scripting.Runtime.LightExceptions.CheckAndThrow (System.Object value) (at <6a70babe64d34e1b9136298538676a61>:0)
Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.FuncCallInstruction`2[T0,TRet].Run (Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.InterpretedFrame frame) (at <6a70babe64d34e1b9136298538676a61>:0)
Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.Interpreter.Run (Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.InterpretedFrame frame) (at <6a70babe64d34e1b9136298538676a61>:0)
Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.LightLambda.Run2[T0,T1,TRet] (T0 arg0, T1 arg1) (at <6a70babe64d34e1b9136298538676a61>:0)
IronPython.Compiler.PythonScriptCode.RunWorker (IronPython.Runtime.CodeContext ctx) (at <4e01c3e2a6d647c6b8da08b7a074e47b>:0)
IronPython.Compiler.PythonScriptCode.Run (Microsoft.Scripting.Runtime.Scope scope) (at <4e01c3e2a6d647c6b8da08b7a074e47b>:0)
IronPython.Compiler.RuntimeScriptCode.InvokeTarget (Microsoft.Scripting.Runtime.Scope scope) (at <4e01c3e2a6d647c6b8da08b7a074e47b>:0)
IronPython.Compiler.RuntimeScriptCode.Run (Microsoft.Scripting.Runtime.Scope scope) (at <4e01c3e2a6d647c6b8da08b7a074e47b>:0)
Microsoft.Scripting.SourceUnit.Execute (Microsoft.Scripting.Runtime.Scope scope, Microsoft.Scripting.ErrorSink errorSink) (at <ab6bb51465f44fb2b67d2937d9bd64f2>:0)
Microsoft.Scripting.SourceUnit.Execute (Microsoft.Scripting.Runtime.Scope scope) (at <ab6bb51465f44fb2b67d2937d9bd64f2>:0)
Microsoft.Scripting.Hosting.ScriptSource.Execute (Microsoft.Scripting.Hosting.ScriptScope scope) (at <ab6bb51465f44fb2b67d2937d9bd64f2>:0)
(wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) Microsoft.Scripting.Hosting.ScriptSource.Execute(Microsoft.Scripting.Hosting.ScriptScope)
Microsoft.Scripting.Hosting.ScriptEngine.ExecuteFile (System.String path, Microsoft.Scripting.Hosting.ScriptScope scope) (at <ab6bb51465f44fb2b67d2937d9bd64f2>:0)
Microsoft.Scripting.Hosting.ScriptEngine.ExecuteFile (System.String path) (at <ab6bb51465f44fb2b67d2937d9bd64f2>:0)
(wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) Microsoft.Scripting.Hosting.ScriptEngine.ExecuteFile(string)
PythonManager.SendPythonRequest (System.Collections.Generic.List`1[T] wind1, System.Collections.Generic.List`1[T] wind2, System.Collections.Generic.List`1[T] wind3, System.Collections.Generic.List`1[T] wind4, System.Collections.Generic.List`1[T] map, WindVector[,] windObject) (at Assets/Scripts/PythonManager.cs:23)
GridManager.Start () (at Assets/Scripts/GridManager.cs:44)
```

this is my C# script:

```
    var engine = Python.CreateEngine();

    ICollection<string> searchPaths = engine.GetSearchPaths();

    //Path to the folder of greeter.py
    searchPaths.Add(Application.dataPath);
    //Path to the Python standard library
    searchPaths.Add(Application.dataPath + @"\Plugins\Lib\");
    engine.SetSearchPaths(searchPaths);

    dynamic py = engine.ExecuteFile(Application.dataPath + @"\greeter.py");
    dynamic TestScript = py.TestClass(wind1, wind2, wind3, wind4, map);

    List<List<float>> ironList = py.generate_predictions(wind1, wind2, wind3, wind4, 315, 10, 10, windObject, true);
    Debug.LogWarning(ironList);
```

Do someone know how do I install this matplotlib.pyplot on my C# project with IronPython?
I saw that on 2012 it's was imposible but maybe today there is a way..
if there is an alternate way to call a metode with parameter from C# to python with the module matplotlib.pyplot I will be happy to know, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long search I discover that IronPython do not support numpy or matplotlib.
So I use the Nuget package to copy my script from python to C# - it's long but working.

this is a link for the nuget package:
https://github.com/GlitchEnzo/NuGetForUnity

after install this package go to Unity → NuGet → Manage NuGet Packages
search for Numpy or matplotlib package and now you can use the python's module.

Answer (score 0):

Packages can be installed with the following command:

```
ipy -m pip install matplotlib
```

See: https://github.com/IronLanguages/ironpython3/blob/master/Documentation/package-compatibility.md

Comment: Do you know where to run this command in the unity project? I try in Assets\Plugins without success

Comment: In Visual Studio: Go to Tools -> Command line -> Developer Command Prompt
to open a cmd window and execute the command in there.

Comment: Matplotlib requires numpy and numpy not supported, as you can see in the link you posted.

Comment: @h4z3 good point

Comment: In fact, I need more the numpy then the Matplotlib, there is a way to call a python function from unity and get an output using numpy?